# Linksys E2500 5GHz not working

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Linksys E2500 and I have been using it in 2.4GHz/5Ghz dual mode for a long time. But as of yesterday I can't connect to, even see the 5GHz network. LAN and 2.4GHz work fine.

This happened once more before and the problem eventually went away, I don't now how or why or how soon it happened. Apparently I'm not the only one having this problem but I couldn't find any solution online.

Here is my configuration:

```
Firmware Version:         2.0.00 build 1  Apr 17, 2014

5 GHz Wireless Settings
Network Mode:             Mixed
Network Name (SSID):      MyWiFi_5G
Channel Width:            Auto (20MHz or 40MHz)
Channel:                  Auto (DFS)
SSID Broadcast:           Enabled
Security Mode:            WPA2 Personal

2.4 GHz Wireless Settings
Network Mode:             Mixed
Network Name (SSID):      MyWiFi
Channel Width:            Auto (20MHz or 40MHz)
Channel:                  Auto
SSID Broadcast:           Enabled
Security Mode:            WPA2 Personal
```

Here are the things I have already tried:

- Using different devices (all of my devices can see and connect to other 5GHz networks)
- Power cycling
- Factory reset
- 30/30/30
- Disabling SSID Broadcast
- Disabling security
- Changing the network mode
- Changing the channel and channel width
- Changing the network name

What else should I try?

If I can't solve it I think am going to try flashing DD-WRT or an older version of firmware, if I can find it.

---

**Edit:**

I noticed that regardless of the configuration, `Status > Wireless Network > 5 GHz Wireless Network` shows N/A for both "Channel Width" and "Channel".

**Edit 2:**

This keeps happening from time to time. [As Phil suggested](https://superuser.com/a/889689/413797) flashing 2.0.00 onto itself works most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't rewrite the flash for it, the 5Ghz emitter may have been damaged. Either that, and/or there's very heavy interference on that frequency (that would of caused the problems initially).

Anyway, to be sure, go to `Basic > Network > Wireless (5Ghz) > Check Enable > Save Button`; then, set your wireless to N-only mode and see if there's any difference. Also make sure SSID on 5GHz is different from the SSID on 2.4.

You can also get the [firmware v 1.0.07](http://support.linksys.com/en-eu/support/routers/E2500) from Linksys. If there is a possibility that it will work, it will work with this version.

Comment: I tried changing all the settings but it didn't help. However, I flashed v1.0.07 and it worked fine, then I flashed v2.0.00 again and it still works fine. It means that there is an issue in v2.0.00. Maybe flashing v2.0.00 on top of itself would have helped but I won't know until it happens again.

Comment: Best use 1007 until theres an official patch note that mentions the issue being fixed.

Comment: Now that I know _a solution_, I am actually hoping that it happens again so that I can try to find other ways to fix it. v2.0.00 was actually fixing some other issues I can't remember. I am accepting you answer for mentioning the firmware version. Even though I couldn't find a way to download it from their website, I found it flashed it and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just flashed the firmware to 2.0 on my Linksys e2500, lost 5ghz band. I immediately re-flashed the same 2.0 firmware and regained my 5ghz band. seems to be doing good. Hope this helps to answer the re-flash question. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Load the Linksys FW, restore to factory defaults and then install tomato again. It should solve the issue, at least it did it twice on my E2500.

Answer (score 0):

My 5Ghz has not worked since updating to V2 of the firmware. Nothing mentioned in any of these threads could resurrect my 5Ghz on V2.

So I flashed down but the overall experience was not as good as V2 - dropped connections etc. So I went back to V2 and lived with only having the 2.4Ghz band.

The other day I was searching for a new channel and tried channel 13 for the first time (had some old devices that could not use 12+) and voila!

**5Ghz and 2.4Ghz working.**
Funny thing is that 5Ghz was broadcasting even when disabled on router when used in conjunction with 2.4Ghz channel 13 (SSID was just blank)

This was specifically for my E2500 V1 and it only works if using CH13 on 2.4Ghz band - your mileage may differ...

Answer (score -1):

Just do a 30/30/30 reset. Hold the reset button down, wait for 30 seconds, then unplug the power while still holding the button down. Now wait for a further 30 seconds and then restore power. Wait 30 seconds more and then let go of the reset button. Your 5ghz network should be back.